# Embed Grizzly (glassfish) Servlet Container with Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, grizzly

Spring boot by default uses Tomcat as an Internal Embedded Servlet Container .
It has also got support for Jetty and UnderTow.

I have build a Restful Application using spring boot . But now i need to deploy it on Grizzly (Glassfish) Servlet Container .

How do i embed my application to run on grizzly as spring dosen't have support for the same.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5015.

Please help as i researched a lot on thistopic but i coudnt get any link that shows how to embed a new Servlet Container for our spring boot app that spring dosent have support for.

Thanks

Comment: If you search for "Grizzly" in the issue tracker, you'll find a closed issue where [the support was requested](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5015) and we declined it. In short, Spring Boot does not support Grizzly and I am not aware of a third party initiative to support it.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll so if we want to deploy our boot application to a grizzly servlet what is the other approach , shall we make a war and then deploy ? i wanted to embedd the servlet by making changes is it possible please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @Andy there is no support for Spring Boot and Grizzly .
Finally i moved to Spring MVC for the same.

Here is the working repo where i embedd Spring MVC with grizzly.
Hope it helps someone.

[Link](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/SpringGrizzly)

Answer (score 2):

The [Grizzly website](https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/dependencies.html) states that Grizzly's servlet support is incomplete:

> This is not a Servlet compliant implementation and as such, not all features exposed by a typical Servlet container are available here.

I haven't seen anywhere that expands on what those missing features are, but there's a good chance that what you're trying to do isn't possible without filling in some gaps in Grizzly's servlet support.

Assuming that it is possible, you need to write Grizzly-specific implementations of Spring Boot's `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` and `EmbeddedServletContainer` interfaces. This is a fairly significant amount of work so, before undertaking it, I would ask yourself what you will gain by being able to use Grizzly as an embedded servlet container versus using Jetty, Tomcat, or Undertow which are already supported out of the box.

If you do decide to tackle this, reading the source code for the existing implementations for Jetty, Tomcat, and Undertow is the best way to learn about what needs to be done:

- [JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/jetty/JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java)
- [JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/jetty/JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java)
- [TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java)
- [TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java)
- [UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/undertow/UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer.java)
- [UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/undertow/UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a third-party implementation of a Spring Boot starter for Grizzly which has specific implementations of the Spring Boot's `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` and `EmbeddedServletContainer` classes for [Grizzly](https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/).

Besides that it also offers JSP support through [Tomcat's Jasper JSP](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) engine, simply by specifying an additional dependency.  You can find the project at [GitHub](https://github.com/dabla/grizzly-spring-boot-starter) and it is also listed in the Spring Boot [starters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters) list.